# Installing program - Vuze torrent client - using .tar.bz2 - vol. 2

Tags: vuze

Program name: Vuze - its a torrent client.
What is needed: installing vuze program.

What I did so far according to one of the users - which actually enabled me to at least run the program.

The work: Terminal -> tar -xjvf VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2

Output: folder with content of package got extracted into Downloads

The work: Terminal -> cd vuze

Output: navigated to vuze folder

The work: Terminal -> ./vuze

Output: the program got opened!

Kyodake - you helped me already!

Conclusion: The program got opened, but the situation is far from resting on the laurels!

Question:

```
Now that the program at least works - what do I have to do further to install it so it appears on list of available apps and I can run it without going through this entire process?
```

My idea: STEP 1: According to a tutorial - the installed programs are usually stored in

/bin/

/usr/bin/

/sbin/

/usr/sbin/

STEP 2: Move the entire Vuze folder into e.g. /usr/bin/

But..what next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note - this application is not single executable, so it is bit hard to install. It was previously packaged for Ubuntu as [Azureus](https://repology.org/project/vuze/versions), but now it is missed in the repositories.

In this particular case you can use [Snap version @ 5.7.6.0](https://snapcraft.io/vuze-vs):

```
sudo snap install vuze-vs
```

---

If you want to install it manually, then you have to install Java Runtime Environment with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

and then do the installation in the correct way by following [ArchLinux PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=vuze) as good reference:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://cf1.vuze.com/files/VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2
tar -xf VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2

sudo mv vuze /opt/vuze

sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/applications/
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/pixmaps/

sudo mv /opt/vuze/vuze /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/vuze /usr/local/bin/azureus

sudo mv /opt/vuze/swt/swt64.jar /opt/vuze/swt.jar

sudo mv /opt/vuze/vuze.png /usr/local/share/pixmaps/vuze.png
sudo mv /opt/vuze/vuze.desktop /usr/local/share/applications/vuze.desktop

sudo sed -i "s|#PROGRAM_DIR=.*|PROGRAM_DIR=\"/opt/vuze\"|" /usr/local/bin/vuze
sudo sed -r -e "s|Exec=$pkgname %f|Exec=$pkgname %U|" \
         -e "s|(x-bittorrent)|\1;x-scheme-handler/magnet;|" \
         -i /usr/local/share/applications/vuze.desktop

update-menus
```